# Color-coded chapter tabs to match flower colors in a field guide

Tags: formatting, color, tufte

I am working on a booklet for my wife who is a grade school teacher. The booklet is field guide about the plants in the fairly large playground area at Gemini Elementary. Tufte-Latex is my "go-to" template for everything these days - especially thanks to this fine group showing me the code to make a change to the color of chapter headings! I am befuddled by another chapter/color task. What I would like to do is assign a little tab of color to associate each chapter with the color of a flower, or green for trees and shrubs. Introductory chapters could just have a white tab so nothing shows up. The colored tabs would be in the table of contents and then at the top, maybe a cm or two from outer corner of each page. Am I nuts for even thinking about doing this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an option meeting all your requirements:

1. Color marking can be activated/deactivated at any point of your document and as many times as required.
2. When color marking is active, each chapter entry in the ToC will have a tab to the left with the corresponding color; the chapter heading will also have this color and all pages of the chapter will also have a colored tab at the top (to the left for even-numbered pages and to the right for odd-numbered pages).
3. The original settings of `tufte-book` for ToC entries and chapter headings are preserved.

#### Simplified version:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifcolor
\colorfalse
\backgroundsetup{
angle=0,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
contents={}
}

\makeatletter
\AddEverypageHook{%
\backgroundsetup{
contents={
  \ifcolor
    \textcolor{\chaptercolor}{\rule{3em}{3em}}
  \fi}
}
\ifodd\value{page}
  \backgroundsetup{
    position={current page.north east},
    hshift=-1.5cm,vshift=-1cm
    }
\else  
  \backgroundsetup{position={current page.north west},
    hshift=1.5cm,vshift=-1cm
    }
\fi  
\BgMaterial}

\def\chaptercolor{black}
\newcommand\normalchapter{%
\colorfalse%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\relax\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}}
  {\itshape\huge\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}
  [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]
}

\newcommand\colorchapter{%
\colortrue%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\relax\color{\chaptercolor}\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}}
  {\itshape\huge\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}
  [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]
}

\newcommand\ContentColor[1]{%
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]
    {\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}\begin{fullwidth}\LARGE\rmfamily\itshape%
      \makebox[0pt]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{1em}{1em}}\hspace{2em}}
    }
    {\hspace*{0em}\thecontentslabel{2em}}
    {\hspace*{0em}}
    {\rmfamily\upshape\qquad\thecontentspage}
    [\end{fullwidth}]
}

\newcommand\ContentNoColor{%
\titlecontents{chapter}%
    [0em]
    {\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}\begin{fullwidth}\LARGE\rmfamily\itshape}
    {\hspace*{0em}\thecontentslabel{2em}}
    {\hspace*{0em}}
    {\rmfamily\upshape\qquad\thecontentspage}
    [\end{fullwidth}] 
}
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \@mainmattertrue%
  \colorchapter
  \fancyhf{}%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@twoside}}%
    {% two-side
      \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{##1}{}}%
      \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\quad\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\plaintitle}}}% book title
      \fancyhead[RO]{\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\leftmark}}\quad\thepage}% chapter title
    }%
    {% one-side
      \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\plaintitle}}\quad\thepage}% book title
    }%
}

\renewcommand\backmatter{%
  \if@openright%
    \cleardoublepage%
  \else%
    \clearpage%
  \fi%
  \@mainmatterfalse%
  \normalchapter%
  \ContentNoColor%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\ChapColor[1]{%
  \def\chaptercolor{#1}
  \ContentColor{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]
\cleardoublepage

\mainmatter
\ChapColor{Maroon!80}
\chapter{Test chapter one}
\lipsum[1-4]
\cleardoublepage
\ChapColor{MidnightBlue!70}
\chapter{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-4]
\cleardoublepage
\ChapColor{Dandelion}
\chapter{Test chapter three}
\lipsum[1-4]
\cleardoublepage

\backmatter
\chapter{Appendix}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

An image of the ToC:

[image]

An image of the document, showing normal chapters and chapters with the color specification:

[image]

Most of the work now is delegated to `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`; in this version, `\frontmatter` activates the color marking for headings, ToC entries and for the tabs on each page of a chapter. `\backmatter` deactivates these settings. The only thing that has to be done now is to use `\ChapColor{<color>}` before each `\chapter` in which a color change is required.

#### First version:

The code:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifcolor
\colorfalse
\backgroundsetup{
angle=0,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
contents={}
}

\makeatletter
\AddEverypageHook{%
\backgroundsetup{
contents={
  \ifcolor
    \textcolor{\chaptercolor}{\rule{3em}{3em}}
  \fi}
}
\ifodd\value{page}
  \backgroundsetup{
    position={current page.north east},
    hshift=-1.5cm,vshift=-1cm
    }
\else  
  \backgroundsetup{position={current page.north west},
    hshift=1.5cm,vshift=-1cm
    }
\fi  
\BgMaterial}


\def\chaptercolor{black}
\newcommand\normalchapter{%
\colorfalse%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\relax\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}}
  {\itshape\huge\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}
  [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]
}
\newcommand\colorchapter{%
\colortrue%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\relax\color{\chaptercolor}\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}}
  {\itshape\huge\thechapter}
  {0pt}
  {\huge\rmfamily\itshape}
  [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]
}

\newcommand\ContentColor[1]{%
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]
    {\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}\begin{fullwidth}\LARGE\rmfamily\itshape%
      \makebox[0pt]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{1em}{1em}}\hspace{2em}}
    }
    {\hspace*{0em}\thecontentslabel{2em}}
    {\hspace*{0em}}
    {\rmfamily\upshape\qquad\thecontentspage}
    [\end{fullwidth}]
}
\newcommand\ContentNoColor{%
\titlecontents{chapter}%
    [0em]
    {\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}\begin{fullwidth}\LARGE\rmfamily\itshape}
    {\hspace*{0em}\thecontentslabel{2em}}
    {\hspace*{0em}}
    {\rmfamily\upshape\qquad\thecontentspage}
    [\end{fullwidth}] 
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\ChapColor[1]{%
  \def\chaptercolor{#1}
  \ContentColor{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]
\cleardoublepage
\colorchapter
\ChapColor{Maroon}
\chapter{Test chapter one}
\lipsum[1-4]
\cleardoublepage
\ChapColor{MidnightBlue}
\chapter{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-4]
\cleardoublepage
\ChapColor{Dandelion}
\chapter{Test chapter three}
\lipsum[1-4]
\cleardoublepage
\ContentNoColor
\normalchapter
\chapter{Appendix}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

From the point where you want the color specifications to be active, add

```
\colorchapter
```

to your document. For each chapter in this section, select the color with

```
\ChapColor{<color>}
```

You can deactivate the color specification at any point using

```
\normalchapter
```

To place the colored marks in chapters with color specification, the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package wes used; this allows you to have complete freedom in the location of the marks.

Comment: When I run that I get about 60 "undefined control sequence} errors and some code up by the tabs on each page: contents=
1.5cm,vshift=-1cm
position=current page.north east, hshift=-                                                 I can't figure out why it won't compile the way yours does.

Comment: @Tim you need an updated version of the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package. Following the link I provided, download the .zip file, run latex on `background.ins` and move the generated `background.sty` file either to your local TDS tree or to your working directory (where your `.tex` file resides).

Comment: @Tim let me know if you have any problems with the installation process and I can give you directly the `.sty` file.

Comment: Works beautifully! That's a wonderful little package. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Tim I added a simplified version of the code that might be of interest for you.

Answer (score 4):

The [`tufte`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tufte) bundle loads the [`titletoc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titletoc) and [`fancyhdr`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fancyhdr) packages, so we can access all of their powerful commands.

In particular, in the code below I have used

```
% format the toc entries for chapter
\titlecontents{chapter}
[0cm]             % left margin
{}             % above code
{%             % numbered format
    {\llap{\color{\chaptercolor{\thecontentslabel}}\rule{.5cm}{.5cm}}\thecontentslabel\hskip .5cm\Large}%
}%
{}         % unnumbered format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}%
```

to format the `chapter` entry in the `toc`.

[image: toc]

I have also used

```
\fancyhead[R]{\color{\chaptercolor{\the\value{chapter}}}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
```

to add a little coloured box to the top of each page.

[image: chapters]

Both of these commands use the command

```
\newcommand{\chaptercolor}[1]{%
    \ifcase#1\relax
    \or
        blue%
    \or
        red%
    \fi%
}
```

to select the color. You'll need to add more colors as you add more chapter.

I took the liberty of numbering your chapters using

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

If your document is different, we'll need to see a MWE.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: animate: {delay: 80}
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{tufte-book}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for colour
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for sample text

\newcommand{\chaptercolor}[1]{%
    \ifcase#1\relax
    \or
        blue%
    \or
        red%
    \fi%
}

% fancy head
\fancyhead[R]{\color{\chaptercolor{\the\value{chapter}}}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

% format the toc entries for chapter
\titlecontents{chapter}
[0cm]             % left margin
{}             % above code
{%             % numbered format
    {\llap{\color{\chaptercolor{\thecontentslabel}}\rule{.5cm}{.5cm}}\thecontentslabel\hskip .5cm\Large}%
}%
{}         % unnumbered format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Sub section}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Sub section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```