# Nice and fancy, super professional looking headers examples

Tags: formatting, header-footer, titlesec, books, book-design

I'm looking for a refresh of my book's headers (it's a French book on physics, in case the content is usefull information).  Currently, I'm using the headers style defined in this MWE code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[pagestyles,medium]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{principal}{
\sethead[\thepage][][\slshape\small\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. \chaptertitle}]{\slshape\small\MakeUppercase{\thesection\ \sectiontitle}}{}{\thepage}
\headrule}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{principal}

\chapter{A first chapter title}
\blindtext[5]
\section{A funny section title}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Another hilarious section title}
\blindtext[5]
\chapter{A funky chapter title}
\blindtext[5]
\section{This section title is really boring}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Really funny section title}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

[image]

These headers are nice and I may stick with them, but I'm looking for some refresh and a modern look.  What other styles could you suggest for an ultra-professional look of the headers?  I'm really lacking imagination and creativity here!

**EDIT:**  I just noticed that I was using *small* fonts in the header (`\small`) while the page number is in normal size.  Is this considered inconsistent?

Using `\slshape\scshape` (with the package `\usepackage{slantsc}` for **slanted Small Caps**), instead of `\slshape\small\MakeUppercase`, appears to give a nice output.

But what should be the appropriate or the common size of the page numbers and the titles, in the headers?

Comment: The question as posted is not suited here. You are asking for opinions.

Comment: For my  taste, look better a non-distracting header, clearly different of man text a text  titles:  a  different (sans serif) and smaller (\footnotesize) font in lower case,  and maybe in gray. But if you are asking about ada boxes, ornaments, backgrounds and so on, my opinion is: apply  the KISS principle ( keep it simple, st... errr .... sir).

Comment: @Johannes_B, I believe that the question and the answers could have great pedagogical value for new comers to LaTeX. I don’t think it’s just a matter of opinions.

Comment: If this is a printed (as opposed as electronic) book the headers and footers should help to locate the position. I find very useful bottom or lateral full color tabs that stick to the border to access the chapters directly, for example. Like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163292/color-coded-chapter-tabs-to-match-flower-colors-in-a-field-guide but fully to the border if the printer can do it (or by trimming the stock)

Comment: Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181081/clickable-chapters-on-the-right-side-of-each-page

Comment: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=33652

Comment: It is *your* document. You decide about the layout. One rule in typography is: there is nothing wrong as long as you have a reason for doing it.